# Why Do I Get Multiple Authorization Requests from Google Sheets Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, authorize

After a few minutes of having authorized the Recorded Macros for a Google Sheets Spreadsheet, I am again asked to reauthorized the project to access my account (still using same browser session).

I visited Google account https://myaccount.google.com/permissions to view "Apps with access to your account," I confirmed the Recorded Macros Apps Script was authorized.

As the image below shows, the Recorded Macro appears as "Has access to Google Docs"

[image: Google account user interface Security page shows the Apps that have access to the user account (https://myaccount.google.com/permissions). In this case, the scope is limited to Google Docs]

However, when I try to run the Apps Script editor, I get a pop up with  the text "Authorization required This project requires your permission to access your data"

[image: Apps Scipt code editor in the background, with modal (i.e., pop up or prompt window) notifying the user that "Authorization required This project requires your permission to access your data"]

The content of appsscript.json is below:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "sheets": {
    "macros": [
      {
        "menuName": "First Macro",
        "functionName": "FirstMacro"
      },
      {
        "menuName": "ImportHTML",
        "functionName": "ImportHTML"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why am I required to authorize the same project multiple times?

P.S. Yesterday, I posted this question at the Google Docs forum, but I got no answer, so here I post hoping to get one. Right now, the name of the recorded macro (i.e., Apps Script project name) is "Recorded Macros (Authorized 20230513 Recorded Macro)" Google documentation indicates I post questions related to Apps Script in this forum:

Comment: Which one of these shows your apps script project name?

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: Also post your `appsscript.json`

Comment: @TheMaster I agree with the image description and alt text; and I have added these. Thank you for pointing this out; I had not thought about it, but as I said, I agree. I added the name of the project and the appscript.json THANX

Comment: Hi, you should post the actual code(espescially in the coding site Stackoverflow) not just the alt text and appsscript.json. Right now, I can't see half of your code even in the picture. Nevertheless, Have you tried a different browser? Tried disabling addons? Enabled cookies? Tried incognito?

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on here but sometimes you authorize the app, then add new code that expands the scopes used - you have to authorize again. HTH

Comment: @u20210512 can you grant access to Google Drive as well? - I have a sample spreadsheet and there I authorize access to Google Docs & Google Drive. I also add on my appsscript.json file the following scopes: `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eveytime we include code that extends the functionality of the Apps Script project, we'll be required to authorized it. This happens as a result of the change in SCOPE for the project.

When I posted my question, Project OAuth Scopes had changed from 1 Scope Requested

- View and manage spreadsheets that this application has been installed
  in   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly

TO

Project OAuth Scopes 2 Scopes

- Requested Connect to an external
  service  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
- View and manage spreadsheets that this application has been installed
  in https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly

In my case, the change in scope happened as a result of my use of the `UrlFetchApp` function within the project's code. As stated here, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization , "Apps Script determines the authorization scopes (like access your Google Sheets files or Gmail) automatically, based on a scan of the code."

As the screenshot below illustrates, we can view the current scope by visiting the overview tab of our projects, and scrolling down to the "Project OAuth Scopes" section.

[image: Apps Script Project Screenshot shows the Overview Tab of the Project which displays details. At the bottom of the image, an arrow points to the OAuth Scopes section.]

The Google Apps Script documentation for the class or service will include information about the scope for it. For example, earlier I mentioned the class UrlFetchApp, and the [introduction to the its documentaiton](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) states:

- This service requires the
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request scope. In
  most cases Apps Script automatically detects and includes the scopes
  a script needs, but if you are setting your scopes explicitly you
  must manually add this scope to use UrlFetchApp.

Within the same document, as we continue to read, we'll find the [Authorization specification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#authorization), which states:

- **Authorization**
  Scripts that use this method require authorization with one or more of the following scopes:
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request

Comment: Your question is a copy of [Why Do I Get Multiple Authorization Requests from Authorized Google Sheets Apps Script Project](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/215452017). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out; I was unaware of my dishonesty, but I will be forthright from now on... cross my heart. I have added the notice of the question I had posted the day before in Google Docs.